# Yii2: How to send a variable from controller to modelSearch?

Tags: php, model, controller, yii2

I have a controller and I need to send a variable to my CarsSearch model but I got this error:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

The search will get cars sold on a certain date using the `$date`. How can I send the `$date` variable?

This is my controller:

```
public function actionCars()
{
    $date = '2020-06-01';
    $searchModel = new CarsSearch($date); // Poblem here in $date.
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('cars', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'date' => $date,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set it to some property like this

```
$date = '2020-06-01';
$searchModel = new CarsSearch();
$searchModel->date = $date;
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

and in your model `CarsSearch` must have property with name `date` and you can call it with `$this->date`

or send this parameter to search function only:

```
$date = '2020-06-01';
$searchModel = new CarsSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $date);
```

Then your function `search` must be

```
public function search($params, $date){
    //here use $date
    .....
}
```

Comment: If the `date` is public property or model's attribute you can also do `$searchModel = new CarsSearch(['date' => $date]);`.

Comment: Yes, i'm agree :)